# Retrieve location data using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'd like to get the location information from the infobox on the following [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama_Department_of_Youth_Services_Schools).

Here is what I've tried:

```
r = requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alabama_Department_of_Youth_Services_Schools', proxies = proxies)
html_source = r.text
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_source)

school_d['name'] = soup.find('h1', 'firstHeading').get_text()
print soup.find('th', text=re.compile("location")).find_next_sibling()
```

output: `None`

Guessing that I'm unable to access the `<td>` element because it's not a sibling??

Any advice?

Comment: Have you tried either searching for "Location" (with the L capitalized) or using re.IGNORECASE?  I'm also not sure why you're using a regexp rather than direct text comparison.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> table = soup.find("table", class_ = "infobox")
>>> name = table.find("th").text
>>> country = table.find("th",text="Country").parent.find("td").text
>>> table = soup.find("table", class_ = "infobox")
>>> name = table.find("th").text
>>> country = table.find("th",text="Country").parent.find("td").text
>>> country = table.find("th",text="Country").find_next_sibling().text #also works
>>> location =  table.find("th",text="Location").parent.find("td").text
>>> location = table.find("th",text="Location").find_next_sibling().text #also works
```

something like that?